# pointer of char and int

Tags: c, pointers, char, int

Hi I have a simple question

```
char *a="abc";
printf("%s\n",a);

int *b;
b=1;
printf("%d\n",b);
```

Why the first one works but the second one doesnot work?
I think the first one should be

```
char *a="abc";
printf("%s\n",*a);
```

I think a stores the address of "abc". So why it shows abc when i print a? I think I should print *a to get the value of it.

Thanks

Ying

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe (probably many times over), but regardless, you should read http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html.

Comment: Also, have you read the `printf` man page?  It describes exactly what is required and how to use it.

Comment: Please try compiling with warnings enabled.

Comment: can you reference a the address 1 like ..its not a correct addres..whereas "abc" returns the address where "abc" is stored

Comment: I think a stores the address of "abc". So why it shows abc when i print a? I think I should print *a to get the value of it.

Comment: As a side note, ou need to change the `b=1` line to `*b=1` to make this fail in the way you intended (instead of failing before you can get that far).

Comment: Most `printf` format specifiers use the *value* of the corresponding argument. `%s` is unusual in that it uses what the argument *points to*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the first one works but the second one doesnot work?

Because in the first, you're not asking it to print a character, you're asking it to print a null-terminated array of characters as a string.

The confusion here is that you're thinking of strings as a "native type" in the same way as integers and characters. C doesn't work that way; a string is just a pointer to a bunch of characters ending with a null byte.

If you really want to think of strings as a native type (keeping in mind that they really aren't), think of it this way: the type of a string is `char *`, not `char`. So, `printf("%s\n", a);` works because you're passing a `char *` to match with a format specifier indicating `char *`. To get the equivalent problems as with the second example, you'd need to pass a pointer to a string—that is, a `char **`.

Alternatively, the equivalent of `%d` is not `%s`, but `%c`, which prints a single character. To use it, you *do* have to pass it a character. `printf("%c\n", a)` will have the same problem as `printf("%d\n", b)`.

---

From your comment:

> I think a stores the address of "abc". So why it shows abc when i print a? I think I should print *a to get the value of it.

This is where the loose thinking of strings as native objects falls down.

When you write this:

```
char *a = "abc";
```

What happens is that the compiler stores a array of four characters—`'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and `'\0'`—somewhere, and `a` points at the first one, the `a`. As long as you remember that `"abc"` is really an array of four separate characters, it makes sense to think of `a` as a pointer to that thing (at least if you understand how arrays and pointer arithmetic work in C). But if you forget that, if you think `a` is pointing at a single address that holds a single object `"abc"`, it will confuse you.

---

Quoting from the [GNU `printf` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (because the C standard isn't linkable):

> d, i
>
> The int argument is converted to signed decimal notation …
>
> c
>
> … the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written…
>
> s
>
> … The const char * argument is expected to be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string). Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) a terminating null byte ('\0') …

---

One last thing:

You may be wondering how `printf("%s", a)` or `strchr(a, 'b')` or any other function can print or search the string when there is no such value as "the string".

They're using a convention: they take a pointer to a character, and print or search every character from there up to the first null. For example, you could write a `print_string` function like this:

```
void print_string(char *string) {
    while (*string) {
        printf("%c", *string);
        ++string;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
void print_string(char *string) {
    for (int i=0; string[i]; ++i) {
        printf("%c", string[i]);
    }
}
```

Either way, you're assuming the `char *` is a pointer to the start of an array of characters, instead of just to a single character, and printing each character in the array until you hit a null character. That's the "null-terminated string" convention that's baked into functions like `printf`, `strstr`, etc. throughout the standard library.

Comment: Is this correct?     WHEN USING CHAR POINTERS P = ENTIRE STRING &P = ADDRESS OF THE POINTER *P = 1RST BLOCK OF THE STRING *(P + 2) = 3RD BLOCK OF THE STRING WHEN USING INT POINTERS P = ADDRESS OF THE CONTENTS P IS POINTING TO &P = ADDRESS OF THE POINTER ITSELF (INT *P's ADDRESS) *P = CONTENTS OF THE POINTER (1 BLOCK OF MEMORY)

Comment: Between the capital letters and the lack of formatting, that's very hard to read—but even once I get past that, I don't understand what your question is. But if you're writing `P = "abcd";`, then `P` is a pointer to the initial `'a'`, which by convention some functions will use as a pointer to a string of characters starting with that `'a'` and ending with the first null character (after the `'d'`).

Comment: So, `*P` is `'a'`, `&P` is a pointer to a pointer to that `'a'`, `P+2` is a pointer to the `'c'` (which can be passed to string functions, which will treat it as the string `"cd"`), `*(P+2)` is `'c'`.

Comment: Thanks but I mean if    char *p="abcd" then print p i can get "abcd". but what about printing *p?

Comment: and when I print p with %c. I get a "?". I dont konw how does this happen

Comment: Since `*p` is a `char`, you can print it like this: `printf("%c", *p);`

Comment: Since `p` is not a `char`, but a `char *`, you can't print it with `%c`. Although this is illegal, it's not a compiler error, because a compiler can't tell that the `%c` in the format string means you need to pass a `char` instead of a `char *`. (A real-life compiler usually _can_ tell, and will give you a warning, but will still compile your code.) At runtime, it ends up interpreting the pointer as an integer, converting it to an unsigned char (which means throwing away everything but the lowest 8 bits), and printing the resulting character, which is going to be arbitrary garbage.

Comment: And don't ignore those warnings. For example, when I try this with clang 4.0, it says `warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *'`. And that's a perfect explanation of the problem. (It even suggests replacing the `"%c"` with `"%s"` to fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

Strings aren't really "first-class citizens" in C.  In reality, they're just implemented as null-terminated arrays of characters, with some syntactic sugar thrown in to make programmers' lives easier.  That means when passing strings around, you'll mostly be doing it via `char *` variables - that is, pointers to null-terminated arrays of `char`.

This practice holds for calling `printf`, too.  The `%s` format is matched with a `char *` parameter to print the string - just as you've seen.  You could use `*a`, but you'd want to match that with a `%c` or an integer format to print just the single character pointed to.

Your second example is wrong for a couple of reasons.  First, it's not legal to make the assignment `b = 1` without an explicit cast in C - you'd need `b = (int *)1`.  Second, you're trying to print out a pointer, but you're using `%d` as a format string.  That's wrong too - you should use `%p` like this:  `printf("%p\n", (void *)b);`.

What it really looks like you're *trying* to do in the second example is:

```
int b = 1;
int *p = &b;
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

That is, make a pointer to an integer, then dereference it and print it out.

Editorial note:  You should get a good beginner C book (search around here and I'm sure you'll find suggestions) and work through it.

Comment: WHEN USING CHAR POINTERS

P = ENTIRE STRING

&P = ADDRESS OF THE POINTER

*P = 1RST BLOCK OF THE STRING 

*(P + 2) = 3RD BLOCK OF THE STRING 



WHEN USING INT POINTERS

P = ADDRESS OF THE CONTENTS P IS POINTING TO 
&P = ADDRESS OF THE POINTER ITSELF (INT *P's ADDRESS)

*P = CONTENTS OF THE POINTER (1 BLOCK OF MEMORY)

Comment: Holy crap that's a lot of capital letters. I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Did you read the FAQ link I posted in a comment above?  What do you mean by 'block' in this context?  Are you trying to say 'byte'?

Comment: I know the solution about the int pointer. So for the char pointer of a. What is stored in *a and what is stored in a? I think *a should store the "abc";

Comment: @saul203: You've told the compiler that `a` is a `char *`—a pointer to a character. So, `*a` _has to be a character_. And it is; it's `'a'`. The reason `printf` can print `abc` instead of just `a` is that it follows the null-terminated string convention: to print a `%s`, it prints the character at `a`, then the character at `a+1`, and so on, stopping as soon as it finds a null character.